# Error message, cannot bind MySQL service to App

Tags: appfog

I get a problem when I try to bind MySQL service to my App (AppFog).

Message : name: VmcError, endpoint: POST:/services, statusCode: 502, code: 503, description: Unexpected response from service gateway

What is the issue?

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem on AppFog side.  502 is bad gateway, so one of the services server on AppFog is not answering.

Try to do the bind from the web UI, try a different infrastructure, or file a support ticket on AppFog.

Comment: I sent my issue on AppFog Support. And now it works, but I have a new issue. See below.

Comment: you should create a new question instead of adding more questions as an answer.  Does your code work locally?  It seems jsdom creates a window without document, and this is why it fails.

Comment: check what your app is doing line 50 of index.js, and log what you pass to jsdom.  It might not be what you expect.

Comment: Line 50 I call JSDOM from module. But there is no errors in local... I think it's a problem with AppFog. Maybe JSDOM is not supported...

Comment: I would think this is something else that fails, then the code passes some junk to jsdom, but without seeing more code, and logs, I can't help much.